# How can I apply color logic like this in gridview?

Tags: gridview, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

I am building a gridview, gridview item source contains index value and other data. I know I can apply background with help of `IValueConverter` binding the background with index property, but I need logic for that. I want gridview like given below.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution, myself :)

```
public class IndexToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        SolidColorBrush _color = null;
        int _val = (int)value % 9;
        switch (_val)
        {
            case 1:
            case 3:
            case 8:
                _color = App.Current.Resources["GreenBrush"] as SolidColorBrush;
                break;

            case 0:
            case 5:
            case 7:
                _color = App.Current.Resources["OrangeBrush"] as SolidColorBrush;
                break;

            case 2:
            case 4:
            case 6:
                _color = App.Current.Resources["PurpleBrush"] as SolidColorBrush;
                break;
        }

        return _color;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int i=0;
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (i == 0)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[0].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Purple;
        e.Row.Cells[1].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        e.Row.Cells[2].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        i++;
    }
    else if (i == 1)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[0].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        e.Row.Cells[1].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        e.Row.Cells[2].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Purple;
        i++;
    }
    else if (i == 2)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[0].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        e.Row.Cells[1].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Purple;
        e.Row.Cells[2].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        i = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not applicable to me because I am working with Windows 8 apps' `GridView` not the ASP.NET `GridView`.